# Mutating an array of symbols

Tags: ruby, symbols, dplyr

I want to mutate an array of symbols by adding an `e` or an `s` to the end of the symbols depending on the last letter of each symbol. For example, the array:

```
[:alpha, :beta, :kappa, :phi]
```

will be modified to:

```
[:alphae, :betae, :kappae, :phis]
```

I can do it using an `if ... else` condition and a regex with an array of strings, but not with symbols. I tried to convert my symbols to strings, mutate them, then convert back, but I get an error

```
s = [:aplha, :beta, :kappa, :phi]

def pluralSym(sym, out = [])
  sym.each do |s|
    s.to_s
    if s.match(/a$/)
      out = s.sub(/a$/, "ae")
    elsif s.match(/i$/)
      out = s.sub(/i$/, "is")
    else
      out = s
    end
    out.to_sym
  end
end

p pluralSym(s)

block in pluralSym': undefined method `sub' for :aplha:Symbol
```

Comment: I wanted to know how you can mutate an array of symbols in Ruby. The question has been answered below. I had an issue with my assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert symbol to string, but you don't assign it and you keep using symbol. Also use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) instead of `each`. A quickfix would be:

```
s = [:aplha, :beta, :kappa, :phi]

def pluralSym(sym, out = [])
  sym.map! do |s|
    str = s.to_s
    if str.match(/a$/)
      out = str.sub(/a$/, "ae")
    elsif s.match(/i$/)
      out = str.sub(/i$/, "is")
    else
      out = str
    end
    out.to_sym
  end
end
```

Comment: This does not mutate the array.

Comment: I've changed it to desctructive operation It mutates now

Answer (score 3):

You can create a method that receives the symbol, the if that matches with `/a$/` or `/i$/`, interpolate the suffix, and converts that to a symbol in each case, otherwise just return sym

```
def plural_sym(sym)
  return "#{sym}ae".to_sym if sym =~ /a$/
  return "#{sym}is".to_sym if sym =~ /i$/

  sym
end

p [:aplha, :beta, :kappa, :phi].map(&method(:plural_sym))
# [:aplhaae, :betaae, :kappaae, :phiis]
```

The `(&method(:plural_sym))` is just a way to call your function passing as argument each element within the block.

Notice here, you're not mutating an array, you're returning a new one.

Answer (score 1):

```
H = { 'a'=>'e', 'i'=>'s' }

def plural_sym(arr)
  arr.map! { |sym| (sym.to_s + H.fetch(sym[-1], '')).to_sym }
end

arr = [:aplha, :beta, :phi, :rho]        
plural_sym arr
  #=> [:aplhae, :betae, :phis, :rho]
arr
  #=> [:aplhae, :betae, :phis, :rho]
```

See [Hash#fetch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

A variant of this follows.

```
H = Hash.new { |h,k| '' }.merge('a'=>'e', 'i'=>'s')

def plural_sym(arr)
  arr.map! { |sym| (sym.to_s + H[sym[-1]]).to_sym }
end

arr = [:aplha, :beta, :phi, :rho]
plural_sym arr
  #=> [:aplhae, :betae, :phis, :rho]
arr
  #=> [:aplhae, :betae, :phis, :rho]
```

See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html).

Answer (score 0):

Symbols are immutable in ruby so you need convert them to string first

```
s = s.to_s
```

Comment: `Object#to_s` does not mutate the object even if it is mutable. This wording makes no sense.